# Entity Framework Data Annotation with type inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a class CashPoint and a class Entity I wish to inherit the primary key for, such that:

```
public class Entity
{

    [Key]
    public int EntityID { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CashPoint : Entity
{ 
//        [Key]
//        public int EntityID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityID")]
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

To be clear, EntityID is both the primary key and the foreign key of the Cashpoint class, whereby other types similar to Cashpoint should inherit from Entity (and have a similar PK/FK structure)

Currently in my db, Entity also has it's own table with it's own PK (of course).

I also do not wish to use fluent mappings (if possible).

Sorry if it's a repeat question but I couldn't find a use-case either in MSDN docs or SO!

EDIT:  the issue is a reported EF error:

Invalid column name 'CashPoint_EntityID'.
Invalid column name 'ServiceType_ServiceTypeID'.

When I create a new Context and set the Service type via DbSet

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: @Mats391 Hi sorry, please see the edit!